# Is 13 a Quadratic residue of 257?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Is 13 a quadratic residue of 257? Note that 257 is prime.

I have tried doing it. My study guide says it is true. But I keep getting false.

Comment: Maybe the thing to do is show how you come to the conclusion that it's false, then people could critique your work.

Comment: What's the contribution of the triple question mark to the title?

Comment: For absolute confidence that the answer is yes, $28^2 = 784 = 3\cdot 257 + 13$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We use somewhat heavy machinery, Quadratic Reciprocity. For typing convenience, we use the notation $(a/p)$ for the Legendre symbol. By Reciprocity, 
$$(13/257)=(257/13)=(10/13)=(2/13)(5/13).$$
This is because at least one of $13$ and $257$ (indeed both) is of the shape $4k+1$.

Note that $(2/13)=-1$ because $13$ is of the shape $8k-3$.

By Reciprocity $(5/13)=(13/5)=(8/5)$.

But $(8/5)=(2/5)^3$, and $(2/5)=-1$.

Multiply. We have $4$ $-1$'s, and therefore $(13/257)=1$.

We could alternately use low-tech methods, by explicitly finding an $x$ such that $x^2\equiv 13\pmod{257}$. Not pleasant!

Comment: But we could use *high-tech* methods to explicitly find $x$.

Comment: Or you could just use a spreadsheet, fill a column with 1 through 256, and fill the next column with $=mod(a1^2,257)$ and sort the data on the squares to see if $13$ is there.  I don't know how $high-tech$ that is.

Answer (score 5):

$\rm mod\ 257\!:\ 13 \,\equiv\, 13\!-\!257 \,\equiv\, -61\cdot 4 \,\equiv\, 196\cdot 4\,\equiv\,49\cdot 4\cdot 4 \,\equiv\, 28^2\ \ $ (took $\,< 10$ secs mentally)

**Remark** $\ $ Because of the *law of small numbers*, such negative twiddling and pulling out small square factors often succeeds for small problems.

Answer (score 1):

Quadratic reciprocity (QR) is the way to go, but a little ingenuity simplifies the solution.

Start with $(13|257)=(257|13)=(10|13)$.  We can't directly apply QR again because $10$ is even.  But, since $13$ is a prime one greater than a multiple of $4$, $(10|13)=(-10|13)=(3|13)$.  Now we apply QR again:  $(3|13)=(13|3)=(1|3)$.

So $(13|257)=(10|13)=(1|3)$.  Through a great deal of arduous effort we find that $(1|3)=1$ so $(13|257)=1$ rendering $13$ a quadratic residue $\bmod 257$.